# How to fix Google Analytics for AMP plugin tracking code?

Tags: google-analytics

Website: https://kidsenglishclass.com
Type of business: Education, English Lessons, Online Classes, English Tutor, English For Kids

Google Analytics tracking tag is installed but not receiving data.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you debug it, you get this error: `The tid (G-0KXVN1M2LR) is not a valid target.`

You're using a wrong id. Well, ok, to be precise, you're using a correct ID. For GA4. But your plugin doesn't expect GA4, it was made for GA UA.

I suggest deleting the plugin, installing GTM instead and have your tracking in there.